# Mage 1.9.2.4 1: 1 website, 1 catalog, multiprice, multicurrency

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4, multicurrency, country-regions

I read many many answers. Many have similar questions, but at the end the solution seems to me to build many websites.

My need: **Magento 1.9.2.4** to implement **1 website** (eg brand.com) with 1 catalog of few products (products are all the same) with **different currencies** and **different prices per country** + **transactions in the currency of the country** NOT the base currency.

**Requirement**: brand.com/US in USD, brand.com/UK in GBP, brand.com/FR in EUR, brand.com/CH in CHF etc Of course the different folders /US /UK /FR etc will have different languages.

**Requirement**: Product1 costs 56 USD in US, 57 CHF in Swiss, 62 EUR in EU, etc Product2 same behaviour, etc

**Requirement**: transactions in US all in USD, in Europe all in EURO, etc

The currency used in transactions must be the one selected by the customer and not the default global one (eg brand.com/US in USD, brand.com/UK in GBP).

**OK** to consider Magento 2.xx and extensions (either for Mage 1.9 or 2.xx)
**OK** to create many stores (but don't want to have many catalogues as the products are the same)

PS Customers don't mix the carts with products from different stores, as once changing the store, the cart resets.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can do it by these 2 extensions:

- Magento 1: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html
- Magento 2: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multiple-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html

In your case, this module solve your issues by: 
+ set base currency for each country, not use the only base currency of the whole website as default Magento. It means brand.com/US in USD, brand.com/UK in GBP,... as you said and of course, transaction is made with base currency of each country.

- Set up different prices for the same products per country as you want. Default Magento doesn't allow you to do this one